# windows permission error when installing packages into a specified library

Tags: r

I seem to have a windows permission error using the following code in R.

```
install.packages("MASS", lib="c:/R/R-3.3.0/libraryMM")
library(MASS,lib.loc="c:/R/R-3.3.0/libraryMM")
```

> Error Message Warning in install.packages("MASS", lib =
>   "c:/R/R-3.3.0/libraryMM") :   'lib = "c:/R/R-3.3.0/libraryMM"' is not
>   writable

I am using windows 8.1.  How to fix?

Note: I had someone ask me to accept their answer and I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: To "accept" an answer click the grayed-out checkmark next in the left margin below the answer score.

Comment: For this question, you probably could solve it by running R "as an adminstrator" (right-click on it when starting it up to see this Windows option), or by creating a library in directory you do have write-permissions for, such as My Documents.

Comment: A google search for "R library permissions windows" would point you to the [R FAQ 4.2](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/rw-FAQ.html#I-don_0027t-have-permission-to-write-to-the-R_002d3_002e3_002e0_005clibrary-directory).